# Error parsing package : Whenever trying to install apk after downloading from the server programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update the app which will not be published to the play store since it is for internal use, I've been able to download the file but while launching an intent to install it getting "Error parsing package"

- I've tried saving the file in the **public directory** as mentioned in few links.
- I've used **FileProvider for getting the URI** since the target device is 8.x.
- I've checked the apk by installing it manually from the file manager app and also adb to make sure there is no problem with the apk.
- I've tried multiple intent actions for installing the app.
- All the permissions are given.

**--Permissions:**

```
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
```

**--Intent codes that I've tired:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);                    intent.setData(FileProvider.getUriForFile(StandardListActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".authorityStr",localFile));    
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            startActivity(intent); 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getPackageName().toString()));               intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(StandardListActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".authorityStr"
                    ,localFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);              installIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(StandardListActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".authorityStr",localFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(installIntent);
```

**--Creating a local file for storage:**

```
File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/blee");
    if (!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }
final File localFile = new File(rootPath, "test2.apk");
```

Want to know if there is anything else I can try and please **do not redirect** me to different threads as probably I've already tried that.

Comment: did the user accept the installing from unknown sources in the phone security options?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.